# Insert HTML element every certain number of children with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

I have an list of unknown number of LI elements. What I want to do is to insert another LI every a certain number of LI.

That is, in example, each 6 (this number could change) LI elemtns I want to insert another one. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

THe main problem is that I do not know the number before, because it comes from a math operation. Can I make this number dynamic? This is what I tried to do:

```
var n  = Math.floor(wd/114);
$('.carousel-inner ul li:nth-child('.n.'n)').after('<div>after</div>');
```

BUt that doesn-t seem to work.

EDIT 2:

I mixed up JS with PHP syntax, I just fixed it by using '+'.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('ul li:nth-child(6n)').after('<li>after</li>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/unjd8/)

---

To have dynamic number

```
var n  = Math.floor(wd/114);
$('.carousel-inner ul li:nth-child(' + n + 'n)').after('<li>after</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is alternate solution if you want.

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Here is jQuery Code.

```
$('#list li').each(function(i,e){
  if (((i+1) % 6) == 0)
    $(this).after('<p>Hello, world.</p>');
});
```

[`JsFriddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/6aFa9/) Demo.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML markup is correct which look something like this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
    <li>some stuff</li>
</ul>
```

then you can use **[nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** selector:

```
$(".list li:nth-child(3n)").after("<li class='newLi'>New Li</div>");
```

to add new `li` after every three list item inside your list, you can change to whatever number you want.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CCLsF/)**

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear if you are modifying an existing DOM UL Element or you are creating a new list all together.

Following code creates a brand new list altogether, since other answers address an existing list.
http://jsfiddle.net/Emjs4/

```
var intersection = 5;
var containerElement = document.getElementById('container');
var listFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    listFragment.appendChild(li);

   if((i+1) % intersection == 0) {
       var liExtra = document.createElement("li");
       liExtra.className = "extra";
       listFragment.appendChild(liExtra); 
   }
}

containerElement.appendChild(listFragment);
```

Please take the time to understand why createDocumentFragment() was used.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment